# Removing noise from an Captcha image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, captcha

[image]

This a sample of captcha image and I want to get rid of salt-pepper noise, curved lines and the blackish background to have proper post-processed image for training. Can anyone help me with it?

I have done the following steps

1. Decreased the contrast of the image
2. Applied a median filter and closed morphological transformation

I tried to remove the background of the image but it was unable to remove the background as it could not detect proper edges.
Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are too many JPEG compression artifacts in the image you have posted. Do you have a PNG version? I there a list assumptions we can make (can we assume the text is colored for example?). Do you expect some kind of general solution, or just solving the specific case?

Comment: I was able to eliminate the spots and curved lines by by median blur and closed morphology, but I am unable to get rid of the blackish background. Simply removing the background is not working.

Comment: Search up "color segmentation" to only extract the blue text into a mask then perform contour area filtering to remove the small noise